# DataVisualization.Charting Empty point

Tags: c#, charts

I am using C# Charting with the X axis as the dates and the Y axis for doubles. I want the X axis to still have a date even if the Y axis doesn't have a point. Right now I'm using:

```
series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 0) { IsEmpty = true });
```

I am also setting the intervals and the numbers show how far apart the intervals are but I need it to show dates.

[image: Charts]

Comment: What exactly is "C# Charting"? Do you mean ".NET Charting"? C# has no charting feature, but .NET has several of them. Which one do you refer to?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

No need to add those point with `0` as its values. You can add the `DataPoints` with the dates you want as the `X-Values`. The [IsEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456677.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property will still do what you have assigned it to do in the [Custom Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456700.aspx)..:

> Changing Empty Point Appearance
>
> Change the visual representation of plotted empty points in applicable
>   chart types using the Series.EmptyPointStyle property. The
>   EmptyPointValue custom property can be used to treat empty points as
>   zeros, or as an average of the points to the left and right of them.
>   For more information on custom properties, see Custom Properties.
>
> The following code demonstrates how to use the Series.EmptyPointStyle
>   property.
>
> // Show marker (red cross) instead of a line for first series.
>   Chart1.Series["Series1"].EmptyPointStyle.BorderWidth = 1;
>   Chart1.Series["Series1"].EmptyPointStyle.BorderColor = Color.Black;
>   Chart1.Series["Series1"].EmptyPointStyle.MarkerColor = Color.Red;
>   Chart1.Series["Series1"].EmptyPointStyle.MarkerSize = 15;
>   Chart1.Series["Series1"].EmptyPointStyle.MarkerStyle =
>   MarkerStyle.Cross;
>
> // Show empty point of second series as thin dotted line (treated as
>   an average). Chart1.Series["Series2"].EmptyPointStyle.BorderStyle =
>   ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
>   Chart1.Series["Series2"].EmptyPointStyle.MarkerColor =
>   Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
>
> // Treat empty point of third series as a zero using the
>   EmptyPointValue custom property.
>   Chart1.Series["Series3"].EmptyPointStyle.BorderWidth = 1;
>   Chart1.Series["Series3"].EmptyPointStyle.MarkerColor =
>   Color.FromArgb(0, 192, 0);
>   Chart1.Series["Series3"].EmptyPointStyle.CustomProperties =
>   "EmptyPointValue = Zero";